# Circle generator in PHP failing on international date line

Tags: php, math, geolocation, gis

I have a circle generator that draws a KML circle around lat and lon. It works fine for 99% of the coordinates I input, however if the location is close to the int'l date line it chokes on the drawing.
I was wondering if anyone has dealt with this issue and could offer a solution.

Here is my loop, if I use the coordinates, I am using 19.282494,166.636650
My radius is 1047NM around this point as it iterates around the point it crosses the int'l date
line. Here is the output at it seems to choke, as it passes thru 0 degrees and 180 degrees

```
<coordinates>166.63665,36.70122262,30 170.33929602,36.39506383,30 173.86075879,35.49288317,30 177.04308391,34.04103068,30 179.76710126,32.10928643,30 -178.04299159,29.78247231,30 -176.42417943,27.15263215,30 -175.38386586,24.31316399,30 -174.90965799,21.35519771,30 -174.97725208,18.36580524,30 -175.55559428,15.42737555,30 -176.60947581,12.617518,30 -178.10014056,10.00900144,30 -179.98458741,7.66939861,30 177.7857603,5.66025581,30 175.26638245,4.0357509,30 172.52041272,2.84094525,30 169.61836825,2.10986796,30 166.63665,1.86376538,30 163.65493175,2.10986796,30 160.75288728,2.84094525,30 158.00691755,4.0357509,30 155.4875397,5.66025581,30 153.25788741,7.66939861,30 151.37344056,10.00900144,30 149.88277581,12.617518,30 148.82889428,15.42737555,30 148.25055208,18.36580524,30 148.18295799,21.35519771,30 148.65716586,24.31316399,30 149.69747943,27.15263215,30 151.31629159,29.78247231,30 153.50619874,32.10928643,30 156.23021609,34.04103068,30 159.41254121,35.49288317,30 162.93400398,36.39506383,30 166.63665,36.70122262,30 </coordinates>
```

```
foreach($ap as $name)
{
    $name=trim(strtoupper($name));
    $circleLat = $airport[$name][0];
    $circleLon = $airport[$name][1];
    $circleRadius = $_GET['circleRadius']*1852;
    $circlePrecision = mostPrecision($circleLat, $circleLon, $circleRadius);
    $coordinatesList = "";
    // Code based on Google Earth community posting by 'ink_polaroid'
    // http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/23634/an//page//vc/1
    $num_points = 36;
    $delta_pts = 360/$num_points;
    // convert coordinates to radians
    $lat = deg2rad(floatval($circleLat));
    $lon = deg2rad(floatval($circleLon));
    $d = $circleRadius;
    $d_rad = $d/6378137; // convert dist to angular distance in radians
    // loop around the compass, appending coordinates of each vertex
    for($i=0; $i<=$num_points; $i++) {  
      $radial = deg2rad($i*$delta_pts);
      $lat_rad = asin(sin($lat)*cos($d_rad) + cos($lat)*sin($d_rad)*cos($radial));
      $dlon_rad = atan2(sin($radial)*sin($d_rad)*cos($lat), cos($d_rad)-sin($lat)*sin($lat_rad));
      $lon_rad = fmod(($lon+$dlon_rad + M_PI), 2*M_PI) - M_PI;
      $coordinatesList .= Round(rad2deg($lon_rad),$circlePrecision).",".Round(rad2deg($lat_rad),$circlePrecision).",30 ";
    }
```

TIA
Steve

Comment: Does this [PHP 3v4l.org fiddle](https://3v4l.org/pXnpf) more clearly illustrate your problem? The negative values are the problem?

Comment: yes, thank you for the fiddle it clearly shows the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your code quite a bit, just circling around the coordinates of the airport.

```
foreach($ap as $name)
{
    $name=trim(strtoupper($name));
    $circleLat = $airport[$name][0];
    $circleLon = $airport[$name][1];
    $circleRadius = $_GET['circleRadius']*1852;
    $circlePrecision = mostPrecision($circleLat, $circleLon, $circleRadius);
    $coordinatesList = "";
    // Code based on Google Earth community posting by 'ink_polaroid'
    // http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/23634/an//page//vc/1
    $num_points = 36;
    $delta_pts = 360/$num_points;
    // convert coordinates to radians
    $lat = deg2rad(floatval($circleLat));
    $lon = deg2rad(floatval($circleLon));
    $d = $circleRadius;
    $d_rad = $d/6378137; // convert dist to angular distance in radians
    // loop around the compass, appending coordinates of each vertex
    for($i=0; $i<=$num_points; $i++) {  
      $radial = deg2rad($i*$delta_pts);
      $lonCircle = $d_rad*sin($radial);
      $latCircle = $d_rad*cos($radial);
      $coordinatesList .= Round(rad2deg($lon+$lonCircle),$circlePrecision).",".
                          Round(rad2deg($lat+$latCircle),$circlePrecision).",30 ";
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
166.63665,36.70122,30
169.66138,36.43659,30
172.59421,35.65074,30
175.34601,34.36756,30
177.83319,32.62601,30
179.98017,30.47904,30
181.72171,27.99186,30
183.0049,25.24005,30
183.79075,22.30722,30
184.05538,19.28249,30
183.79075,16.25776,30
183.0049,13.32494,30
181.72171,10.57313,30
179.98017,8.08595,30
177.83319,5.93897,30
175.34601,4.19743,30
172.59421,2.91424,30
169.66138,2.1284,30
166.63665,1.86377,30
163.61192,2.1284,30
160.67909,2.91424,30
157.92729,4.19743,30
155.44011,5.93897,30
153.29313,8.08595,30
151.55159,10.57313,30
150.2684,13.32494,30
149.48255,16.25776,30
149.21792,19.28249,30
149.48255,22.30722,30
150.2684,25.24005,30
151.55159,27.99186,30
153.29313,30.47904,30
155.44011,32.62601,30
157.92729,34.36756,30
160.67909,35.65074,30
163.61192,36.43659,30
166.63665,36.70122,30
```

Of course, without the returns, which are only there, in the result, for clarity. See [this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/YfbuD).

I have no idea if this will actually work in your Keyhole Markup Language application, that's something you need to try.

Comment: Wow thank you for updating the loop it worked perfectly when I uploaded it to google maps.